# How do I get email from another account (sent through POP) deleted from that account when I delete it from my account that the POP send it too?

Tags: gmail, google-account, account-management, pop3

That was a little wordy, but basically what I meant is that I have POP enabled for my work account to see messages sent to my home account. Whenever I delete a message sent to the home account, from the work one. The email always stays on the home one. Is there any way I can make it so that if I delete a home email in my work account it will also delete it in my school account?

Answer (score 1):

Access the emails using IMAP not POP and you will be able to synchronize the mail folders across all your devices.